# Log for two different SVN paths in the same repository

Tags: svn

For example returning the log comments for two branches, "*BranchA*" and "*BranchB*" can be done separately with two separate SVN commands.

`svn log svn://REPO/branches/BranchA`

`svn log svn://REPO/branches/BranchB`

Is it possible in Subversion to return the logs for two separate locations simultaneously as a single log via a single SVN command?

Answer (score 1):

`log: Show the log messages for a set of revision(s) and/or path(s).
usage: 1. log [PATH][@REV]
       2. log URL[@REV] [PATH...]`

`svn log` only accepts a single path, but you can do an svn log operation on the parent level:
`svn log svn://REPO/branches/`  and filtering them intelligently some other way (perhaps with `svn log -v` which will show the full repo path of changed files)

Understandably, this may not be what you're actually looking for since it will return the logs for every branch instead of the two you're looking for. You're probably better off either:

1. doing two `svn log` operations and merging them intelligently, or
2. considering a different approach to the problem you're attempting
   to solve.